# Rewrite a series of if statements in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Maybe it's just too late at night, but I can't seem to figure this one out. I'm creating something that looks like this

```
(defn new-psf
  [props]
  (let [psf (Psf.)]
    (if (contains? props :pageLn)
      (.setPageLn psf (props :pageLn)))
    (if (contains? props :pageNum)
      (.setPageNum psf (props :pageLn)))
    (if (contains? props :includedSources)
      (doseq [s (props :includedSources)]
        (.add (.getIncludedSources psf) s)))
    psf))
```

Now this looks pretty ugly and I have to think that with the repetitive pattern there is a cleaner way in Clojure. None of the cond* functions seem to fit. I'm not good enough with macros myself to create something new.

Anyone have any ideas for a macro that would let me do something like this:

```
(defn new-psf
  [props]
  (let [psf (Psf.)]
    (condd (partial contains? props)
      :pageLn (.setPageLn psf (props :pageLn))
      :pageNum (.setPageNum psf (props :pageNum))
      :includedSources (doseq [s (props :includedSources)]
                         (.add (.getIncludedSources psf) s)))
    psf))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your Psf class is, so let's do this on a familiar one

```
(def frame (doto (new javax.swing.JFrame) 
                 (.setContentPane (javax.swing.JPanel.))))
```

Properties map

```
(def props {:title "test" 
            :background java.awt.Color/blue 
            :buttons ["foo" "bar" "baz"]})
```

Instead of a series of `if`s you can use a map

```
(def option-application 
       {:title (fn [x v] (.setTitle x v)) 
        :background (fn [x v] (.setBackground (.getContentPane x) v))
        :buttons (fn [x v] (doseq [btn v] (.add x (javax.swing.JButton. btn))))})
```

And apply based on `props`

```
(doseq [[k v] props] ((k option-application) frame v))
```

Let's look at our beautiful frame

```
(doto frame (.pack) (.setVisible true))
```

If a key is missing in props, it's corresponding action in option-application will never be called. If order matters, use an array-map.

Note there is still a lot of repetition, since for every key I am wrapping a similarly named setter.  [Seesaw](http://github.com/daveray/seesaw) deals with all this using reflection. See `apply-options` there, which should be general enough to use on your class. Seesaw also has a `cond-doto` you might want to borrow.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like `condd` is almost the same as `condp`?

```
(defn new-psf
  [props]
  (let [psf (Psf.)]
    (condp (contains? %2 %1) props
      :pageLn (.setPageLn psf (props :pageLn))
      :pageNum (.setPageNum psf (props :pageNum))
      :includedSources (doseq [s (props :includedSources)]
                         (.add (.getIncludedSources psf) s)))
    psf))
```

You could even use the rarely useful :>> syntax in condp with a few changes:

```
(defn new-psf
  [props]
  (let [psf (Psf.)]
    (condp (get %2 %1) props
      :pageLn :>> #(.setPageLn psf %)
      :pageNum :>> #(.setPageNum psf %)
      :includedSources #(doseq [s %]
                         (.add (.getIncludedSources psf) s)))
    psf))
```

Comment: Thanks, Alex! I tried to make `condp` work earlier but with the arguments for `contains?` in the wrong order I didn't think it would work. Just one small fix if someone else runs across this to do `#(contains? %2 %1)` or `#(get %2 %1)` so that the pred is a function.

Comment: this is different from the listed code, because it will stop at the first match, rather than executing all matches

Comment: Dang. You're right. I could have sworn it was working last night. Back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 3):

If I read you right, whether the first `if` test fails or succeeds, the following conditionals are still tested ?

Sounds like a job for `cond->` ! Unlike `condp` it does not short-circuit evaluation to the first match.

```
(defn with-page-ln [psf v]
  (.setPageLn psf v)
  psf)

(defn with-page-num [psf v]
  (.setPageNum psf v)
  psf)

(defn with-included-sources [psf v]
  (doseq [s v]
    (.add (.getIncludedSources psf) s))
  psf)

(defn new-psf
  [props]
  (cond-> (Psf.)
          (contains? props :pageLn)          (with-page-ln (props :pageLn))
          (contains? props :pageNum)         (with-page-num (props :pageLn))
          (contains? props :includedSources) (with-included-sources (props :includedSources)))
```

Comment: I think you mean "whether the first `if` test fails _or succeeds_, the following conditionals are still tested", i.e. unlike `condp` it does not short-circuit evaluation to the first match.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thank you ! If you don't mind, I'll update my answer with your words.